# Репозитории пользователя github и сортировка

Tags: php, github-api

Вообщем, решил я поработать с api github, ради интереса. И вообщем сделал вот такую функцию:

```
$repositories = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'https://api.github.com', 'requestConfig' => [
        'format' => Client::FORMAT_JSON
    ], 'responseConfig' => ['format' => Client::FORMAT_JSON]]);
    $response = $client->createRequest()->setUrl('users/' . $user . '/repos')
               ->addHeaders(['content-type' => 'application/json', 'accept' => 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
                             'User-Agent' => 'Moonwolf45'])
        ->setContent('{sort: "updated", direction: "desc"}')->send();
    $rep = json_decode($response->content);
    $repositories[] = $rep;
}
```

Вообщем-то ничего сложного, пробегаемя по списку пользователей и тянем репозитории каждого, но проблема даже не в том, что ограничение 100 штук, а в том, что сортировка не работает `->setContent('{sort: "updated", direction: "desc"}')` как видите я передаю нужные данные, но при этом все равно получаю:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
            ...
            [updated_at] => 2019-02-04T15:55:12Z
            ...
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
            ...
            [updated_at] => 2021-05-09T17:11:46Z
            )
    )
```

Сортировать уже полученные результаты совсем не дело. Кто сталкивался с этим??

Answer (score 0):

[Ссылка](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user)

Проверьте что вы отправляете запрос методом GET.

[Пример](https://api.github.com/users/torvalds/repos?sort=updated&direction=desc)

Comment: Давайте более развёрнутый ответ

Comment: @Vitalii Rudnykh Впринципе работать начал, после того как я переписал на curl запрос, с httpclient расширением не хотел правильно получать данные даже когда get поставил.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем так работает:

```
$curl = curl_init();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/users/' . $user . '/repos?sort=updated&direction=desc');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'content-type: application/json',
        'accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json',
        'User-Agent: Moonwolf45',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $rep = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    if (!empty($rep)) {
        $repositories = array_merge($rep, $repositories);
    }
}
curl_close($curl);
```